# Get latest record for a period of months and aggregate its value using Oracle PL-SQL for each ID

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have an Oracle stored procedure that takes input parameters as two date ranges.
e.g.

```
sp_periodic_data(p_from_date DATE, p_to_date DATE) // let's take p_from_date = 01-Jan-2021 and p_to_date = '03-31-2021'
```

I need to pick the latest record for each month from the table and add its corresponding value for the time period.

Table Value :

| ID | Date | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1-jan-2021 | 10 |
| 1 | 10-jan-2021 | 20 |
| 2 | 15-jan-2021 | 15 |
| 2 | 16-jan-2021 | 20 |
| 2 | 02-feb-2021 | 10 |
| 2 | 06-feb-2021 | 15 |
| 1 | 17-feb-2021 | 10 |
| 1 | 5-mar-2021 | 15 |
| 1 | 17-mar-2021 | 10 |
| 2 | 10-mar-2021 | 10 |

Expected output: Need to add the latest record (latest date) for each ID for every month between Jan to March

```
40 --> for ID 1 (20+10+10)
45 --> for ID 2 (20+15+10)
```

Comment: Please  post a [mcve]. where is the code forsp_periodic_data?

Answer (score 0):

for a start :

[SQL for Beginners](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/sql-for-beginners-the-group-by-clause-and-having-clause)

[Aggregate Functions](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions003.htm#SQLRF20035)

[Analytical SQL in Oracle Database 12c](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/bi-datawarehousing/wp-in-database-analytics-12c-2132656.pdf)

example:

```
with 
list_dates(id,dates,value) as
(
select 1,'1-jan-2021',10  from dual union all
select 1,'10-jan-2021',20 from dual union all
select 2,'15-jan-2021',15 from dual union all
select 2,'16-jan-2021',20 from dual union all
select 2,'02-feb-2021',10 from dual union all
select 2,'06-feb-2021',15 from dual union all
select 1,'17-feb-2021',10 from dual union all
select 1,'5-mar-2021',15  from dual union all
select 1,'17-mar-2021',10  from dual union all
select 2,'10-mar-2021',10  from dual
)
,step1 as (
select 
id, trunc(to_date(dates,'dd-mon-yyyy'),'mm') mm,max(value) keep(dense_rank last order by to_date(dates,'dd-mon-yyyy')) value
from list_dates
group by id ,trunc(to_date(dates,'dd-mon-yyyy'),'mm')
)
select id,sum(value) val from step1
group by id;
```